# keeping first field in html form after submitting then have a master submit button after someone is done with the first field

Tags: php, html, scripting, forms

I am currently using this php form to submit into our mySQL database with a "chip_number" and "order_number" also with a date and time stamp. We want to use this with no keyboard or mouse, just a scanner. Currently it tabs the first field and when the second field is scanned the form is submitted, which is working as intended but it completely starts the form over, i would like it to keep the first field (order_number) after submitting so we can scan multiple "chip_numbers" on the same "order_number" then have a Master submit button if you will to send it all through when the employee is done with that order number and start with a blank form. This is the script i am using.  thanks to all in advance!

```
   <!-- Insert -->
<?php
$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MICROCHIP_TBL (chip_number,order_number)
VALUES 
('$_POST[chip_number]','$_POST[order_number]')";

IF (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: TRY AGAIN HUMAN!";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<html>
<head>
<!-- Validate form function -->
<!--<script type="text/javascript">
//  function validateForm()
//  {
//    var x=document.forms["chip_insert"]["order_number"].value;
//    var y=document.forms["chip_insert"]["chip_number"].value;
//    if (x==null || x=="")
//    {
//      alert("Please enter an Order Number.");
//      document.forms["chip_insert"]["order_number"].focus();
//      return false;
//    }
//    if (y==null || y=="")
//    {
//      alert("Please enter a Microchip Number.");
//      document.forms["chip_insert"]["chip_number"].focus();
//      return false;
//    }
//  }

</script> 
-->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getNextElement(field) {
    var form = field.form;
    for ( var e = 0; e < form.elements.length; e++) {
        if (field == form.elements[e]) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return form.elements[++e % form.elements.length];
}

function tabOnEnter(field, evt) {
if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
        if (evt.preventDefault) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        } else if (evt.stopPropagation) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            evt.returnValue = false;
        }
        getNextElement(field).focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="document.chip_insert.order_number.focus();">
<center>
<h1>Jeffers HomeAgain Microchip Entry</h1>


<form name="chip_insert"  id="chip_insert" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Order Number: <input tabindex="1" maxlength="11" type="text" name="order_number"  id="order_number"  required="required"onkeydown="return tabOnEnter(this,event)" /><br /><br />
Tag Number: <input tabindex="2" maxlength="15" type="text" name="chip_number" id="chip_number" required="required" /><br /><br />
<input tabindex="7" type="submit" />
</center>
</form>
```

Comment: To keep values after submit, just print them back into the form in the `value` attribute of the form elements (that is, of the `<input>` tags).

Comment: If you are just scanning, how is the `form` going to know when to start with a blank ordernumber?

Comment: @developwjk I am trying to get the value syantax correct, so far it's still submitting without returning the "order_number" back into the field.  Any insight into exactly how it should be typed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`header('Location: http://JVSIntranet/microchip/homeagain.php');`

This code redirects back to the form, I guess. You should add the ordernumber so it can be picked up by the form.

```
$ordernr = $_POST['order_number'];
header("Location: http://JVSIntranet/microchip/homeagain.php?order_number=$ordernr"); //mark the double quotes
```

in your form code you will have to use something like

```
  <?php  $value = (isset($_GET['order_number'])) ? " value=$_GET['order_number'] " : ""; ?>
    Order Number: <input tabindex="1" maxlength="11" type="text" name="order_number" id="order_number" <?php echo $value; ?> required="required"onkeydown="return tabOnEnter(this,event)" /><br /><br />
```

Comment: I know the "value=GET or POST" should be the answer but so far no matter how i put it in it still submits and never calls the "order_number" back into the field.  This is the way i have it now, sorry i'm a bit new to this submit field process.

Comment: POST is when submitted by a `form`, GET is when added to the URL. Does the `URL` when returning from a submit have the `?order_number=` part?

Comment: Yep, now i just need it to put it in the order number field

Comment: And where exactly do i put $value = (isset($_GET['order_number'])) ? " value=$_GET['order_number'] " : "";  I have it in the script area now but nothing happens, if i put it in the form area it shows on the page and still doesn't even work at that point.  or is my echo $value just not correct and it's not calling it?

Comment: It should go where your `form` is, before the Order Number line is printed. I have changed the code, added the PHP-tags.

Comment: well the php tags would makes sense so it wouldn't act like text on the actual page but now after it submits it doesn't return the page, just gets an error.

Comment: I've been trying stuff all morning, but i'm almost positive that the echo value in the input line is fine, so it's just a matter of calling from the $value line and without breaking or displaying it on the page, driving me nuts.

Comment: well the problem is mainly because i have 2 php files, one for connecting to server and one for the script and the form.  In the server connect php, the add "order_number" to the URL worked because that is where the $_POST takes place, now that i got the order number in the url i need a way to call it from the input line, i dont think $_GET will work because it's on the other php file, unless i combined the two files but i'm not sure how much i would have to change to get that all working properly again.  Anyway i can just echo $ordernr somehow? or the order number part in the URL?

Comment: i haven't got it yet but you're answer is right to what i wanted, looks like my biggest problem is that after the form posts it goes back to the header that's at the bottom of the post script so it just negates the value function and refreshes the page.  I suppose i will have to rewrite a new script to allow these capabilities. If you have any suggestions feel free to let me know.  Thank for the help!

Comment: your messages are confusing. Can you update the code to what you have now and put the names of the files in there too. That makes it easier to reference to them.

Comment: Yes i can sorry, i added both files on the same script just to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it. i had to take out the Return function from my form and i added this to my script:

```
$value = "";
    if( isset( $_POST ["order_number"] )) $value = $_POST ["order_number"];
```

then i put this in my input line and it works fine:

```
value="<?php echo $value; ?>"
```

Comment: Glad you could get it to work. You applied the suggested approached just in slightly different `wording` :)